# Xpath - extract column after column

Tags: xml, xpath, html-table, extract

I'm using XPath similar to this:

```
//*[ends-with(@id,'eoId')]/table/tbody/tr/td
```

and it extracts table data as array. E.g. table of structure

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
```

that is rendered as

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

is extracted as array

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

array.

What I need as a result is the following format:

```
1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

I can use XPATH 2.0. Thanks.

Comment: Is the number of rows known in advance? E.g. are there always 2 rows?

Comment: No, rows and columns vary all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XPath 2.0 expression that does this:

```
for $table in //*[ends-with(@id,'eoId')]/table,
    $col in 1 to count($table/tr[1]/td),
    $row in 1 to count($table/tr)
  return $table/tr[$row]/td[$col]/text()
```

[Try it here.](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/77e66464663eb448f4fa5971e3d4aaa7)

Input:

```
<div id="a_eoId">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Result: the sequence

1
5
2
6
3
7
4
8

This XPath solution assumes that all rows have the same number of columns (or at least, that no row has more columns than the first row).

Answer (score 0):

Consider a slight transformation using xslt on the `<tr>` node and then use your xpath query(). Various programming languages and softwares have XSLT processors including Java, Python, PHP, Excel/Access with VBA, Saxon, and others:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template name="tdsort" match="tr" >
  <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="//td">                          
          <xsl:sort select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>             

  </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All other nodes in original xml can remain same structure with `<xsl apply-templates select="."/>`. Above stylesheet would transform original xml into the following:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
```

From there you can use XPath:

```
 //*[ends-with(@id,'eoId')]/table/tbody/tr/td
```

Comment: +1 Good idea in general. However... (a) your for-each loops over `//td` (all td's) again for each `tr`. So you'll output all td's twice, in this example. Maybe you meant `for-each select="td"`? (b) In that case, the concatenation of `count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1` in the sort key seems redundant. All the `td` in the for-each loop have the same parent, so this part of the key will be identical and will have no effect on sort order.

Comment: Good catches @LarsH. For a) I tried your suggestion, and only the first 4 `td` nodes were processed not all 8. And you are right about b) indeed concatenation was redundant.